# await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(User) does not issue new key in cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I develop app in asp core with identity and tickets.
Part of Program.cs looks like

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

MemoryCacheTicketStore memoryCacheTicketStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MemoryCacheTicketStore>(memoryCacheTicketStore);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(356*100);//on server
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.SessionStore = memoryCacheTicketStore;
    options.Cookie.Name = "identity_token";
});
```

MemoryCacheTicketStore.cs looks like

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

public class MemoryCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public MemoryCacheTicketStore()
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }

    public async Task ClearAll()
    {
        _cache.Dispose();
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var key = DateTime.Now + guid.ToString();
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }

    public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
        var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        if (expiresUtc.HasValue)
        {
            options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiresUtc.Value);
        }
        options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(100*356));//on server
        _cache.Set(key, ticket, options);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        _cache.TryGetValue(key, out ticket);
        return Task.FromResult(ticket);
    }

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        _cache.Remove(key);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I am trying to have a new ticket key in cookie after each
`RetrieveAsync(string key)`
So every `RetrieveAsync(string key)` in am trying to have a new one in cookie.
I used
`await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(User)` in controller at start of action
BUT it does not issue new key in cookie

How to make a new key appear in ticket cookie?
I understand below code would do but I need to make proper cryptography

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();

MemoryCacheTicketStore memoryCacheTicketStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MemoryCacheTicketStore>(memoryCacheTicketStore);

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(356*100);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.SessionStore = memoryCacheTicketStore;
    options.Cookie.Name = "identity_token";

    options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = async context =>
    {
        // Generate new key -> as I do not know CRYPTOGRAPHY METHODS
//those need to be implemented
        var newKey = GenerateNewKey();
       
        // Save new key in cookie
        SetNewKeyInCookie(context.HttpContext, newKey);
       
        // Optional: actualise new key on server MemoryCacheTicketStore
        // ...

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

Those need to be verified:

private string GenerateNewKey()
{
    using (var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        rng.GetBytes(key);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(key);
    }
}

private void SetNewKeyInCookie(HttpContext context, string newKey)
{
    var options = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = context.Request.IsHttps,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
    };
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("identity_token", newKey, options);
}
```

How to make valid cryptography so that asp would understand ticket key value?

The ASP code in dropdown.pl -> cookie@encryptedTicket -> cookie_ticket.zip changes cookie BUT ASP would not uderstand it
and on subsequent requests it thinks cookie is invalid and does not read cookie ticket key.

HOW to make proper cookie with key value so that it is encrypted
in way that ASP would understand?

Comment: Even signing out and singing in user fails to help in page controller. There is still same key given to store.

Comment: Why do you want the key to change in the first place?

Comment: In general, it's not a common practice to update the key used to retrieve an authentication ticket in ASP.NET Core's ITicketStore. The key is typically a unique identifier, changing it could lead to complications and potential issues with session management and authentication.

Comment: think of ticket to be used only once so after use it is new ticket issued and replaced old. then if someone takes that ticket or steals it then after first use it is replaced with new so owner looses original ticket and have to login again to obtain new ticket. then system knows that someone else uses original ticket so it solves problem that someone else may know login details. if someone else logins then system knows that there are more tickets in use so account owner knows that someone else knows login details

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375548/key-for-ticket-in-asp-ticket-store-for-login

Comment: here what microsoft says to change cookie middleware

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs

Comment: here is middleware that has to be modified

Comment: dropdown.pl -> cookie@encryptedTicket-> cookie_ticket.zip here is source code to be modified. What cookie to write so that ASP understands the new KEY? HAVE to MIGRATE first and login with windows login automatically:install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools for migration
>> PM
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database

Comment: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html

Comment: here in this link solution my be services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));